# How can I reduce execution time of a query

Tags: mysql

When I run this query, it takes almost around 30 min to complete. How can I reduce the execution time?

```
INSERT INTO vfusion.attendance_report_data_2
    SELECT 
        CONCAT(attendance_checkin.userid, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(IFNULL(attendance_checkin.work_date, 0)))) AS id,
        attendance_checkin.userid, 
        attendance_checkin.work_date,
        attendance_checkin.checkintime_data as in_time,
        attendance_checkout.checkouttime_data as out_time,
        IFNULL(attendance_checkin.work_shift,0) as work_shift
    FROM 
        vfusion.attendance_checkin
    INNER JOIN 
        vfusion.attendance_checkout ON attendance_checkin.userid = attendance_checkout.userid
                                    AND attendance_checkin.work_date = attendance_checkout.work_date
     ON DUPLICATE KEY 
          UPDATE
              in_time = in_time,
              out_time = out_time,
              work_shift = attendance_checkin.work_shift
```

These are my tables - I have a lot of data in this table

```
CREATE TABLE attendance_checkout 
(
    id_attendance_checkout BIGINT(11) NOT NULL,
    userid INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    work_date DATE DEFAULT NULL,
    checkouttime_data DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    work_shift INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_attendance_checkout)
)  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=LATIN1;

CREATE TABLE attendance_checkin 
(
    id_attendance_checkin BIGINT(11) NOT NULL,
    userid INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    work_date DATE DEFAULT NULL,
    checkintime_data DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    work_shift INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_attendance_checkin)
)  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=LATIN1;

CREATE TABLE attendance_report_data_2 
(
    id_attendance_report_data BIGINT(11) NOT NULL,
    userid INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    work_date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
    in_time DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    out_time DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    work_shift INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (id_attendance_report_data , in_time , out_time , work_date , userid , work_shift)
)  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=LATIN1
```

I need to run this query randomly but for taking log time I can't run it. 
Because it's stuck all other

Comment: We have no way of knowing, without your schema, a query plan, some sample data...

Comment: You should also specify your target platform and MySQL version

Comment: You need to give us more detailed info about your schema, relations and perhaps some test data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an index for the combination of columns [userid] and [work_date] in table [vfusion.attendance_checkout]

This speeds up the JOIN